# Use SimpleDateFormat to validate a date

Tags: java, validation, date, simpledateformat

I want to create a method to validate a date by using `SimpleDateFormat`.

If the date is valid(e.g. `02/09/2012` or `2/09/2012` or `02/9/2012`), this method should return **true**.

But if the format of the date is wrong(e.g. `02/09/201X`) or logically wrong(e.g. `32/09/2012`), this method should return **false**.

I try to write this method like this:

```
private boolean isValidDate(String date) {
        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MM-yyyy");
        DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
        Date d = null;
        String s = null;

        try {
            d = df1.parse(date);
        }catch (Exception e1) {
            try{
                d = df2.parse(date);
            }catch (Exception e2) {
                try {
                    d= df3.parse(date);
                }catch (Exception e3) {
                    return false;
                }
                s = df3.format(d);
                return date.equals(s);
            }
            s = df2.format(d);
            return date.equals(s);
        }
        s = df1.format(d);
        return date.equals(s);
    }
```

But if I validate a date, for instance, `2/09/2012`, it returns **false** (actually it should return **true**). I have no idea why... Can anyone find what's the problem with my code, or this logic is totally wrong? Is there any better way to do this validation?

Comment: You should consider using java.xml.DatatypeFactory to parse date strings. It's fast and supports a large number of standard formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is in the format 2/09/2012 not 2-09-2012, so your dateformat should be like below:

```
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy");
    DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is fine (but not very scalable - try to do it in a for-loop in case you add more formats later).

The problem is that your format strings are wrong. Instead of `dd-MM-yyyy` you should have `dd/MM/yyyy`. The same goes for the rest of the formats:

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy");
DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I found that using `setLenient(false)` would shorten the code, because I don't need to compare `date.equals(s)`...

Answer (score 1):

The validation fails because `/` isn't `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this additional check after parsing each string:

1. Tokenize the value of the date String
2. Then use the extracted day, month and year values to create a new Date object using GregorianCalendar
3. Compare this to the date object you created from parsing the date strings
4. If they match then you know that the input string contained a valid date format